# Optimize jQuery Toggle on hundreds of elements

Tags: jquery, dom, toggle

I have hundreds of elements on a page that share a class, and I need to optimize the application jQuery `Toggle()` to keep my browser from locking up when applying the function as follows:

```
$j('.textDate').toggle() //this locks up this browser
```

Clicking this function causes the browser to lock up and freeze -- so I've tried to break it into a loop and run the function on each element individually and than I need to figure out some timeout/breaking up of the array to keep the browser from freezing:

```
$j('#showDatesCheckbox').click(function(){
    var textdate = $j('.textDate'); //1000+ elements
    for(var i = 0; i < textdate.length; i++)
    {
          $j(textdate[i]).toggle();
    }
});
```

This still doesn't work though?

Comment: Animating 1000 elements is probably locking the browser. Why you couldn't just hide them?

Comment: perhaps wrap them in a div and hide the div instead?

Comment: @MartinsBalodis according to jquery: `.toggle()` is equivalent to doing `.show()` or `.hide()`

Comment: @f0x ...they're dynamically built onto the page and it's hundreds of rows, there isn't any way to apply them to the page without having them independently have specific location settings...

Comment: Just as a tip here on speed, if you calculate the length first, your loop will execute more quickly. e.g. var len = textdate.length; for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) { $j(textdate[i]).toggle(); } The reason for this is that the number of elements in the textdate collection is calculated on each execution, but is known in advance, so doing the above saves you the lookup and count each execution.  Also, if you can, cache the $j('.textDate'). element outside the click event if this number doesn't change after the page is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a question.

What about `var $textDates = $('.textDate');` to cache the results.

Then, later you can call `$textDates.addClass('hidden');`

The cached list should make the subsequent operations faster to implement.

I've added a jsFiddle.net one to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/cRRcC/2/

This adds 30,000 elements to the page (divs) and then gives you a link to hide them.

This seems to take less than a second this way.  Would something of this order help you?

Thanks,
AE

Comment: thanks for the jsFiddle, this is definitely the new standard - I couldn't get `.toggle()` to work with any efficiency but a combination of this and a bit of timeout every 25 records sped things up - I'll write a demo in the pots if anyone wants it.

Answer (score 0):

Animating 1000+ elements in a browser won't work in my opinion. Why not use simply `$j(textdate[i]).toggle()` which toggles visibility of elements. If you want to be fancy you can try to animate only those elements that are visible to the user.

Comment: ...? this is what I am doing -- it doesn't work `.addClass('myClassforHiding')` doesn't work... it still takes a _long time_ to find and add the class to all of the elements and locks up the browser.

Comment: Have you tried $j('.textDate').toggle() instead of your own for loop?

Comment: see my first line of code `$('.textDate').toggle()` _locks up the browser_ I think it takes jQuery too much energy to traverse the DOM and show or hide these elements individually...

Comment: You can try and code some of the jquery stuff yourself. If you know that you are hiding the elements apply the rules yourself and don't use $.fn.hide, e.g. $(el).css('display','none') or use add/remove class. I have done this a time ago with this jQuery plugin which uses node caching extensively https://github.com/thomaspeklak/jquery-livequery/blob/master/jQueryLiveQuery.js example (only ~250 entries): http://thomaspeklak.github.com/jquery-livequery/example.html - I know that this one can handle 1000+ nodes.

Comment: thanks! I will have a look...it does perform very well on a large list of elements - but I'm hoping there is a faster optimization, but if not I'll get into applying it...